# Matrix reconstruction by SVD in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, matrix, svd, symmetric, matrix-decomposition

Suppose A is a symmetric matrix whose SVD is A= USV^T, and let B = U\sqrt{S}V^T, then B^2 should be equal to A.

But when I implemented it using tensorflow, B^2 and A does not match. Highly appreciated if you could give some advice!

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aIvr.png)

Comment: Please share the code as plain text to be able to reproduce your problem/question.